operación de coluymnas con dataframe resultante de un groupby en pandas
Compañeros, un saludo:
Recreo lo que necesito
Tengo un dataframe que se genera luego de aplicar un groupby

necesito cambiar los nombres de "mean y std" por "promedio y desviación estándar"
necesito crear una nueva columna resultado de dividir estas dos columnas "std / mean"

el programa lo tengo así:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base = pd.DataFrame({'grupo': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2'], 'valor': ['5', '7', '3', '2', '5']})
base['grupo'] = base['grupo'].astype('category')
base['valor'] = base['valor'].astype('int64')

# genero el nuevo dataframe con el comando groupby
resumen = base.groupby(['grupo']).agg({'valor':['mean', 'std']})

# observo cual es eel nombre de las columnas del nuevo dataframe
nombrecolumnas = resumen.columns.values

# comando para cambiar nombre de columnas
resumen.rename(columns={"('valor', 'mean')": 'promedio', "('valor', 'std')": 'ds'})

# comando para generar la nueva columna en el dataframe que es la división entre std/mean  
resumen['cv'] = resumen["('valor', 'std')"] / resumen["('valor', 'mean')"]

Pero lastimosamente nada de esto me funciona
Agradezco la colaboracion.

Si quieres renombrar el segundo nivel simplemente tienes que hacer:
resumen.rename(columns={'mean': 'promedio', 'std': 'ds'}, level=1, inplace=True)

Mediante el argumento level especificas el nivel de los nombres a reemplazar, en este caso es el segundo nivel (1, dado que se indiza a partir de 0).
En realidad funciona sin especificar el nivel en este caso, aunque fuerzas a pandas a buscar las columnas a lo largo del árbol:
resumen.rename(columns={'mean': 'promedio', 'std': 'ds'}, inplace=True)

Es importante que uses inplace=True o que reasignes a resumen o el renombrado se perderá en el vacío...
Por otro lado, cuando indices sobre un multiindex en vez de usar una cadena representando la tupla con el nombre (niveles) de la columna, indiza usando directamente la tupla:
resumen[('valor', 'ds')]

o directamente:
resumen['valor', 'ds']

o también se puede usar la "selección parcial" encadenando:
resumen['valor']['ds']

Por lo tanto:
resumen.rename(columns={'mean': 'promedio', 'std': 'ds'}, level=1, inplace=True)
resumen['cv'] = resumen[('valor', 'ds')] / resumen[('valor', 'promedio')]


>>> resumen
          valor                  cv
       promedio        ds          
grupo                              
1      6.000000  1.414214  0.235702
2      3.333333  1.527525  0.458258


